# Extending PHP helper methods

Tags: php, oop

For `deleteBarDocument()`, I wish not to implement

```
$this->getModel()->updateParentAudit($this->audit_table,$_POST['id']);
```

in the `deleteDocumentHelper()` helper method, but implement something else such as

```
$this->bla($_POST['id']);
$this->blabla($_POST['id'],$_POST['doc_id']);
```

How can I extend `deleteDocumentHelper()` for `deleteBarDocument()`, but leave it as is for `deleteFooDocument()`?

Normally, I would just replace

```
$this->getModel()->updateParentAudit($this->audit_table,$_POST['id']);
```

with

```
$this->doSomething();
```

and create a `doSomething()` method with whatever code is needed.  The probably with this approach is it will affect both  `deleteFooDocument()` and `deleteBarDocument()` which is not desired.

Or should I pass the helper method an anonymous function?  I am cautious of doing so as I've been warned that anonymous function should be used sparingly.

```
<?php
class parentController
{
    protected function deleteDocumentHelper($type){
        if(isset($_POST['id'],$_POST['doc_id'])){
            if(documents::removeDocument($type,$_POST['doc_id'],$_POST['id']))
            {
                $success=1;
                //Ability to replace the following line with one or more lines
                $this->getModel()->updateParentAudit($this->audit_table,$_POST['id']);
            }
            else {$success=0;}
            header('Content-Type: application/json;');
            $this->dontCache();
            echo(json_encode(array('success'=>$success)));
        }
        else {exit($this->missingPage());}        
    }
}  

class childController extends parentController
{
    public function deleteFooDocument(){$this->deleteDocumentHelper('foo');}
    public function deleteBarDocument(){$this->deleteDocumentHelper('bar');}
}

//Application creates childController object, and evokes apprpropriate method based on GET/POST  
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say:

> Normally, I would just replace
>
> ```
> $this->getModel()->updateParentAudit($this->audit_table,$_POST['id']);
> ```
>
> with
>
> ```
> $this->doSomething();
> ```
>
> and create a `doSomething()` method with whatever code is needed. The probably with this approach is it will affect both  `deleteFooDocument()` and `deleteBarDocument()` which is not desired.

But, why not in following way?

```
class parentController
{
    protected function doSomething()
    {
        $this->getModel()->updateParentAudit($this->audit_table,$_POST['id']);
    }

    protected function deleteDocumentHelper($type){
        if(isset($_POST['id'],$_POST['doc_id'])){
            if(documents::removeDocument($type,$_POST['doc_id'],$_POST['id']))
            {
                $success=1;
                //Ability to replace the following line with one or more lines
                $this->doSomething();
            }
            (...)
        }
        else {exit($this->missingPage());}        
    }
}  

class childController extends parentController
{
    private $somethingElse = False;

    protected function doSomething()
    {
        if( $this->somethingElse )
        {
            // Your deleteBar code 
        }
        else
        {
            parent::doSomething();
        }
    }

    protected function deleteDocumentHelper( $type, $somethingElse=False )
    {
        $this->somethingElse = $somethingElse;
        parent::deleteDocumentHelper( $type );
    }

    public function deleteFooDocument(){$this->deleteDocumentHelper('foo');}
    public function deleteBarDocument(){$this->$this->deleteDocumentHelper('bar',1);}
}
```

With this approach you can substantially leave untouched the parent class, and apply different code(s) only when needed.

Comment: Thanks fusion.  Yea, I could do so, but it doesn't seem real clean.  I am not saying your solution is not clean, but what I am doing is not.  I might be doing this way backwards...

Comment: In fact, you want extend `parentController->deleteDocumentHelper` or modify their own code?